# Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of defineProps in vuejs

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

[how to remove this error or avoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msCxb.png)

to remove error because very annoying anyone who can help I appreceate it
everytime I viewed my code I thought I have an error because of color red in vscode by the error is the local declaration of defineProps or anything that already used without importing

Answer (score 1):

`defineProps` is more of a compiler macro then an actual function

Thus it's defined in the SFC scope

You shouldn't import it from `vue`, it's already there

Solution: just remove it from `import` line

Comment: But I have a new issue after removing the defineProps 'defineProps' is not defined

Comment: .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { endOfLine: "auto" }],
  },
};